# I'm not able to perform any action on elements of the page displayed after successfully logged in

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer, ui-automation

I'm working on automation testing using jest and puppeteer. I need to login first and then execute a testcase on the page displayed after successfully logged in.

I'm able to perform all action in login page but it is not identifying my locators on page displayed after login.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you waiting for the page to load after login?

```
await ...login...
page.waitForSelector('#myId'); // replace with a selector of the page after login
// so what you want in this new page
```

For debug purpose i suggest you the screenshot function:

```
await ...login...
page.waitForSelector('#myId');
await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' }); // you now see what puppeteer sees
```